# Stuck installing MongoDB on Mavericks OSX 10.9 brew install hangs at scons line

Tags: mongodb, osx-mavericks, scons

```
brew install mongodb
==> Downloading http://downloads.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r2.4.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mongodb-2.4.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading patches
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file src/third_party/v8/SConscript
patching file src/third_party/v8/src/spaces.h
==> scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8 -j4 --64 --cc=/usr/bin/clang --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++
```

hangs indefinitely (10 min +).

here are the processes:

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
428 ttys000    0:00.14 -bash
439 ttys001    0:00.14 -bash
425 ttys002    0:00.20 -bash
2472 ttys002    0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb inst
2491 ttys002    0:00.17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0 -I /usr/local/Library/Homebrew 
2517 ttys002    0:08.25 python /usr/local/bin/scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8 -j4 --64 --cc=/usr/bin/cla
2583 ttys002    0:00.02 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=
2584 ttys002    0:05.63 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -trip
2599 ttys002    0:00.02 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=
2600 ttys002    0:02.10 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -trip
2605 ttys002    0:00.02 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=
2606 ttys002    0:01.81 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -trip
2607 ttys002    0:00.02 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=
2608 ttys002    0:01.70 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -trip
1351 ttys003    0:00.22 -bash
```

I have tried:

1. Updating Xcode command line tools for Mavericks
2. Updating Python

Comment: 10 minutes isn't "indefinitely"; how long did you let it run? The latest Homebrew recipe is compiling MongoDB from source, so may take longer than you expect. You can see more details during compilation with `brew install -v mongodb`. Instead of building from source in Homebrew, another option is to [download the binaries](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) from mongodb.org.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was in the same situation today where it took more than 20 minutes for homebrew to install mongoDB (2.4.8 on Mavericks). It "hung" in clang and MBA fans went berserk. Give it more time.

Comment: Good to hear, I'm waiting right now. I shut down my vm's to free up some resources hopefully cut down the time.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue, 12.3 minutes. Thanks for the answer

Comment: 17 files, 252M, built in 11.0 minutes

Comment: On OSX 10.11.3:
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.4: 17 files, 260.7M, built in 47 minutes 46 seconds

I have a slower machine as well (2.66 GHz Core 2 Duo)

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle verbose debug mode by running:

```
brew install -vd mongodb
```

That will give you a LOT more output, so you'll see everything that's happening and know it's not hanging.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I just did an upgrade on Mac OS 10.8.5 and it took almost 45 minutes from source.  Using MacPorts `sudo port install mongodb` (currently MongoDB 2.4.9). On a mid-2011 Macbook Air 4GB RAM it pinned the 4 CPUs with up to 8 clang processes during the build.  XCode 5.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

~brew update
~brew install mongodb

This sped up the installation on my mac. Downloaded in 5 minutes.

This link was very helpful 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I ran brew update first, and this his how long it took to install MongoDB on OSX 10.6.8:

==> Summary
/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.5: 17 files, 407M, built in 123.7 minutes

I was searching around trying to figure out how much longer my fans were going to be blasting when I found this thread.

Comment: Also OSX 10.6.8: Summary  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.5: 17 files, 408M, built in 52.2 minutes

Comment: OSX 10.10.1 Late 2013 MBP /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.6: 17 files, 333M, built in 18.3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. try to run:

```
brew update
```

before running the install

Answer (score 0):

since this is a thing

/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.3: 17 files, 275MB, built in 66 minutes 52 seconds

stick with it took me over an hour

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, on Mac OS 10.11.6 with a 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5 processor, it took more than 1 hour to complete.

If you are using MacPorts, you can make sure the compilation is still ongoing by examining the tail of the compilation log

```
tail -f /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_databases_mongodb/mongodb/main.log
```

The `-f` option allows live tracking of the file.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand if you are also having this problem, have a solution or commenting on the question.

Comment: I also have this problem. 
At some point I thought the compilation was stuck, and I found a way to make sure the compilation was still ongoing.